# CodeIgniter Default Controller not found

Tags: php, codeigniter

In routes.php i've set the default controller as so:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'index_controller';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

index_controller is in the controllers folder titled: `index_controller.php`
The content of `index_controller` is:

```
<?php
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Index_controller extends CI_Controller {

 function __construct()
 {
   parent::__construct();
 }

 function index()
 {
   $this->load->helper('url');
   $this->load->view('login_view'); 
 }

}
?>
```

The error I get is:

404 Page Not Found
The page you requested was not found.

Comment: which version of codeigniter are you using??

Comment: @user3574766 Rename `$route['default_controller'] = 'index_controller';` to Just `$route['default_controller'] = 'Index'` (Take note the Captial `I`)

Comment: Route can point to lower case name, but if it is CI v3+ your controller file need to be ucfirst (i.e. `Index_controller.php`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the version of your codeigniter is 3, then file name should start with capital letter.

Next, have you added `.htaccess` file ?? if not access the url with index.php.
or use following code to remove the index.php from url.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /CI/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

add this file in root with name `.htaccess`

Comment: Did the answer helped you?? Please add comment here what you had missed in your code. It will hwlp others.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `index_controller` is a Controller name, not URL. You should write URL.

For example;

```
$route['default_controller'] =  'home';
$route['home']               =  'back/homeController';
```